# using expression to label corrplot

Tags: r, expression, r-corrplot

I'm trying to visualize a big correlation matrix using `corrplot`

```
library(corrplot)
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,5,3,7,9), b=c(6,5,7,2,3), c=(seq(1,10,2)))
cm <- cor(df)
corrplot(cm)
```

So, far everything works fine, however, I want my variables to be named something like.
`expression(paste(Delta, " (LW"[""%up%""], " Stefan-Boltzmann(T"["2m"],"))"))`
or `expression("LW"%down%" (PIR)")`

[In this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) I found that starting a string with ":" tells `corrplot` to evaluate and expression, however, 
`":Delta Druck zu 14T-Mittel"`
gives me

```
Error in parse(text = substring(s, 2)) : <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol
1:  Delta Druck
           ^
```

and trying to add %down% in the first place tells me that it can't find the function %down% when trying to use it as a column name. Is there a workaround?

Thanks a lot.

---

Edit after the comment of Roland:
I tried

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,5,3,7,9), b=c(6,5,7,2,3), c=(seq(1,10,2)))
cm <- cor(df)


rownames(cm)<- c(":'Delta Druck zu 14T'-'Mittel'","b","C")

corrplot(cm)
```

which gave me this result:
[image: Delta not parsed :(]

unfortunately it did not parse the Delta

Comment: Try `":'Delta Druck zu 14T'-'Mittel'"`. The error message indicates that you did not pass a valid expression.

Comment: Please study `plotmath`. Apparently you want `rownames(cm)<- c(":Delta * 'Druck zu 14T'-'Mittel'","b","C")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Roland I was abel to figure out the answer, which is a combination of single and double quotes and the `*`

```
rownames(cm)<- c(":Delta * 'Druck zu 14T'-'Mittel'",
                 ":Delta * '(LW'[''%up%'']*')'",
                 ":Delta * ' LW'[''%up%'']* ' Stefan-Boltzmann(T'['2m']* ')'")

corrplot(cm)
```

apparently the star has to come in front of every part, that does not have to be evaluated, single quotes can be used instead of double ones and calls with %% have to be framed by double-single quotes.

Thank you!

Comment: A `*` simply means juxtaposition of two elements.